# Modify non-registry based Group Policy In C++

Tags: c++, windows, gpo

I want to change group policy settings in my C++ code.

I know I should use the `IGPEInformation` or `IGroupPolicyObject` functions, but how use them for non registry based polices like this one?
this one hasn't got a key in registry
(I found it in cis-microsoft-windows-7-benchmark pdf)

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings
    \Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Allow log on locally
```

Comment: Hi nazanin, can you share the solution you found here? Me too looking for this..